# How to use scrollreveal js offline?

Tags: javascript, scrollreveal.js

I need to use scrollreveal js on my website. But I cannot use it online all the time.
So can anyone help me find out how to use scrollreveal js offline

Need to use scrollreveal js offline

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "use offline"? What do you mean exactly by "use online"? How do you currently use it? Typically you can get the javascript file(s) and include them in your page without a CDN. They also support the package manager NPM to manage your dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save content as js file to project folder.

https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@4.0.0/dist/scrollreveal.min.js